# How to get the trimmed value 88 out of 0.0.88 in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to get the value 88 out of 0.0.88 using groovy. Is there any easy way to get that.

Comment: do you mean `replaceAll("0\\.", "")` ?

Comment: Your solution works, but my intention is to get anything after second .

Comment: Something like "0.0.88".split(".")[2] which currently throws me error out of bound exception

Comment: You need to split by `\\.`

Comment: It works with \\. aswell as tokenize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tokenize()` instead of `split()`

```
assert "0.0.88".tokenize('.')[2] == '88'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it looks like you are trying to get seconds from a date.
Here is one approach:

```
String theDate = "28/09/2010 16:02:43";
def newdate = new Date().parse("d/M/yyyy H:m:s", theDate)
log.info newdate.getSeconds()
```

Or if you just have the time part of the date, the following works too:-

```
String theDate = "16:02:43";
def newdate = new Date().parse("H:m:s", theDate)
log.info newdate.getSeconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is likely more nuanced than stated, but taken at its face value, I'd just do:

```
assert '0.0.88' - '0.0.' == '88'
```